# how to fix bug intent and sound effect in a button?

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

when first time I click my button it goes to next activity without any problem but when I press the back button and click the same button again the app is crashing, here is my code, the bug is on button 1, the 2nd button works well without sound

```
wc = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.welcome);
        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Intent svc = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(svc);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                wc.start();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                Handler hd = new Handler();         
                hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        Intent ttrial = new  Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondMain.class);
                        startActivity(ttrial);
                        ttrial.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    }
                    },3000 );   

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

Remove this flag from code

```
 ttrial.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Write below code

```
Intent ttrial = new  Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondMain.class);
startActivity(ttrial);
finish();
```

if you used `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` this flag, if the activity already exists at the top of the current task then a new instance will not be created that may cause a problem.

if you want to use this flag then write code like this.

```
Intent ttrial = new  Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondMain.class);
ttrial.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);  
startActivity(ttrial);
```